# Complex SQL Update Statement across two tables, with condition within condition and calculation - Help Needed

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-update, conditional-statements

Two tables:

CART (CartID, UserID, DateCreated, ProductID, ProductName, Size, Price, **Quantity**, **Subtotal**, **HoursWork**)

PRODUCTS(ProductID, Name, SDescription, Price, Size, Images, Thumbnail, Weight, LDescription, Stock, CategoryID, **HoursWork**)

I am working on the cart/basket page of an e-commerce site. Specifically:
"+" link button to increase quantity of selected product by 1 in the cart, and
later the "-" link button to decrease quantity of selected product by 1 in the cart.

As well as the **Quantity**, the **Subtotal** and **HoursWork** fields of the Cart table need updating. Subtotal: to calculate the overall total order price. HoursWork: to calculate the number of hours needed for a booking slot.

So far I have an SQL statement to check Products.**Stock** for a value > 0

If this condition is met, then an SQL statement will run to update the Cart,
(**Quantity** = Quantity + 1, **Subtotal** = @Subtotal + @Price WHERE CartID = @CartID) and Products (**Stock** = Stock - 1 WHERE ProductID = @ProductID).

I am struggling to include **HoursWork** for the Cart. So I've created a new SQL Statement for testing. I need the Cart.HoursWork field, to add the Products.HoursWork field value for the same ProductID, within the cart.

So far I have:

```
"UPDATE Cart
SET HoursWork = HoursWork + 
                SELECT HoursWork
                FROM Products
                WHERE Products.ProductID = Cart.ProductID
WHERE CartID = @CartID"
```

And earlier I tried:

```
"UPDATE Cart
SET HoursWork = Cart.HoursWork + Product.HoursWork
                WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
FROM Cart, Products
WHERE CartID = @CartID"
```

*The cartID, ProductID, ProductName, Size, Price, Quantity, Subtotal, HoursWork and Weight for each item in the cart is stored in variables so easily accessed.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your code would work if it were syntactically correct.  Subqueries must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
UPDATE Cart
    SET HoursWork = (HoursWork + 
                     (SELECT p.HoursWork
                      FROM Products p
                      WHERE p.ProductID = Cart.ProductID
                     )
                    )
WHERE CartID = @CartID;
```

Comment: Brilliant, my statement works now. I am using "Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand" "cmd1.CommandText = 'Update...'" I am trying to run both statements at once so cmd1.CommandText = "Update Statement 1" + "Update Statement 2" however when I do this none works. Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: I have made two separate Commands, cmd1 and cmd2, and now everything works.